# Integration of bivariate lognormal density function

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, probability-density

```
rho = 0.8;

ff = @(x, y) (exp(-(((log(x)-10).^2 - 2.* rho .* (log(x)-10) .* (log(y)-10)+(log(y)-10).^2)./(2 .* (1-rho.^2))))./(2.*pi.*sqrt(1-rho.^2).*x.*y));

syms x y
vpaintegral(vpaintegral(ff, x, [0 inf]), y, [0 inf])
```

**Why is the above integration of bivariate lognormal density function in Matlab not 1?**

Note: the log transformation of this lognormal bivariate random variable is a bivariate normal random variable with a mean (10, 10), and covariance matrix (1, rho, rho, 1).

Answer (score 3):

**Using** [**`integral2`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html)**:**

we get 0.9994,

```
% MATLAB R2019a
rho = 0.8;
ff = @(x, y) (exp(-(((log(x)-10).^2-2.*rho.*(log(x)-10).*(log(y)-10)+(log(y)-10).^2)./(2.*(1-rho.^2))))./(2.*pi.*sqrt(1-rho.^2).*x.*y));

area = integral2(ff,0,inf,0,inf)     % area = 0.9994
```

but adjusting the tolerance gives the desired result.

```
area = integral2(ff,0,inf,0,inf,'Method','iterated','AbsTol',0,'RelTol',1e-10)
```

> ans = 1.0000

```
format long
area
```

> ans = 0.999999999999998

Not too shabby.

---

**Using** [**`vpaintegral`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpaintegral.html) **from the Symbolic Toolbox:**

You can also [adjust the tolerance](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpaintegral.html#bvaf9ay) for [`vpaintegral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpaintegral.html).

Using a [Relative Error Tolerance](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpaintegral.html#bu_z2sx-RelTol) of `1e-4` got the job done. This parameter greatly affects computation time.

```
syms x y
area = vpaintegral(vpaintegral(ff, x, [0 inf],'RelTol', 1e-4, 'AbsTol', 0), y, [0 inf],'RelTol', 1e-4, 'AbsTol', 0)
```

> area = 1.0

Comment: Thanks, but why vpaintegral doesn't work. I got ans =
 
0.00547892 by using vpaintegral, big difference.

Comment: @user53154 I think it is a tolerance issue.  See my updated answer. Feel free to comment if concerns persist.